# CSS scale margin down to zero based on screen size

Tags: css, responsive-design, margin

I am able to scale a website's margin based on the screen's size by using vw or % units.  However, I would like it to scale at a greater rate, the smaller the viewport is. So while there may be the full 10% margin when the browser window has filled a full 1920x1080 monitor, I would like the margin to be 0% when displayed on a mobile device such as an android phone.

I can accomplish an abrupt change in margin with the below css, but how could I make it a smooth downscaling of the margin?

```
.my-class{
    margin: 0 10%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    .my-class{
        margin: 0 0%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `calc()` function to calculate the margin based on the view width. The function you are looking for is:

```
margin: 0 calc(100vw * 0.1352 - 67.6051px);
```

I obtained the function using the math equation to find the equation of a line given 2 points ([reference](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/linear_equation/write-equation/equation-of-line-given-two-points.php)). The two points are `(1920, 192)` (192 is 10%) and `(500, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add transition property to it and it will work

```
.my-class{
    margin: 0 10%;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the transition property? It provides an animation between css states and should also provide a css animation when switching media. Although this is unlikely to be observed by anyone who isn't using a development screen.

```
 .my-class{
margin: 0 10%;
transition: all ease 500ms;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    .my-class{
        margin: 0 0%;
        transition: all ease 500ms;
    }
}
```